# Generate word document from directory listing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several directories of files (shell, Perl, and SQL) that I use for building books and doing healthchecks of databases. What I am trying to do is take the directory and produce a Word document which should hopefully look like:

```
(Heading-2) file-name (no spacing) the filecontents (page break).

Repeat until done.
```

What I'm getting with the code that I mostly reused below is

```
(Heading 2) file name (Heading 2) next file name (until end of directory)
```

followed by the contents of the files. What would I need to do to make this work like I want?

```
Sub DirLoop()

Dim MyFile As String, Sep As String, OFolder As String

Dim wdDoc       As Document
Dim txtFiles    As Document

  ' Sets up the variable "MyFile" to be each file in the directory
  ' This example looks for all the files that have an .xls extension.
  ' This can be changed to whatever extension is needed. Also, this
  ' macro searches the current directory. This can be changed to any
  ' directory.


  Sep = Application.PathSeparator
  OFolder = openFolder
  Sep = "\"
     ' Look for the right type of file.....

     MyFile = Dir(OFolder & Sep & "*.sh")

  Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

  ' Starts the loop, which will continue until there are no more files
  ' found.

  Do While MyFile <> ""

     ' Get the directory


     Set txtFiles = Documents.Open(FileName:=OFolder & "\" & MyFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False)
    Selection.InsertBreak (wdPageBreak)
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    Selection.TypeText Text:=MyFile & vbCr
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("No Spacing")


    wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter txtFiles.Range.Text & vbCr
    txtFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False
     MyFile = Dir()
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I made some improvements to the layout of your question to make it more clear what the actual question is. The indentation of your code seems all over the place though, and I am not familiar enough with vba to know what the defacto standard of indentation is for that. You'll have to fix that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you're mixing the `Selection` and `Range` objects. When you open a document the Selection will be at the beginning of the document. Everything you add to the document using `Selection` will be at the beginning.

`wdDocRange.InsertAfter`, on the other hand, will insert at the *end* of the document.

Generlly, accepted practise is to use the `Range` object rather than the `Selection` object whenever possible. There's more than one way to write code to do what you intend, my approach would look more like this (untested since I'm on a mobile device):

```
Sub DirLoop()

  Dim MyFile As String, Sep As String, OFolder As String
  Dim txtFiles As Word.Document, wdDoc as Word.Document
  Dim rngNewEntry as Word.Range

  ' Sets up the variable "MyFile" to be each file in the directory
  ' This example looks for all the files that have an .xls extension.
  ' This can be changed to whatever extension is needed. Also, this
  ' macro searches the current directory. This can be changed to any
  ' directory.

  Sep = Application.PathSeparator
  OFolder = openFolder
  Sep = "\"
 ' Look for the right type of file.....

  MyFile = Dir(OFolder & Sep & "*.sh")

  Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument

  ' Starts the loop, which will continue until there are no more files
  ' found.

  Do While MyFile <> ""

     ' Get the directory

     Set txtFiles = Documents.Open(FileName:=OFolder & "\" & MyFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False, ConfirmConversions:=False)

     'Content is a property, so more "correct" for use than Range
     Set rngNewEntry = wdDoc.Content
     rngNewEntry.Collapse wdCollapseEnd 'Puts focus at end of doc
     rngNewEntry.InsertBreak wdPageBreak
     rngEntry.Text = My File & vbCr
     'Format Range after adding text
     rngEntry.Style = wdDoc.Styles("Heading 2")
     rngEntry.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
     rngEntry.Range.Text = txtFiles.Content.Text & vbCr
     rngEntry.Style = wdDoc.Styles("No Spacing")

     txtFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False
     MyFile = Dir()
  Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: As things usually go, I got hung up in another idea and just now got back to this today.     Thanks very much !  The code got me 98% of the way and with a minor bit of tweaking I now have something that will create a document with one script/sql/ per page, which could be handy printing it off or for notes